# Bootsrap Navbar-Brand as Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello so I am working on a homepage of our webapp, and I would like to know how to fix (*or any runarounds available for this, if you may*) this code of mine in the bootstrap CSS.

1.) I am working on a navbar, and I want the navbar-brand to be a dropdown menu. Well yeah, I implemented it, (*see picture below*) but as you can see, it is not **ALIGNED** to the navbar. How do you align it in the bootstrap.css?

[image]

2.) Also, I placed an image logo, and I want to **highlight it with the brand when it hovered and clicked**. What changes do I add to the CSS? Or better yet, how do I do this? Should I a.) Import the image into a character of that specific font, or b.) I just add some changes to the bootstrap.css that makes the images/glyphicons highlight?

[image]

Or any form of aid or help will do, even workarounds. Much appreaciated, thanks. :D

---

**HTML SOURCE CODE**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="Header" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><p><img src="pictures/logo.png" id="HeaderLogo" height="25" width="15"> Home <span class="caret"></span></p></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="BrandDropdown" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" id="DropdownDivider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchBar">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="SearchToggle"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="SearchLogo"></span></span></a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**CSS SOURCE CODE**

```
#Header {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  border: 0px;
}

#HeaderLogo {
  opacity:0.5;
}

#BrandDropdown {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  border: none; 
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  position: left;
}

#DropdownDivider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
  margin: 10px 12px;
}

#SearchBar {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  border: none;
}

#SearchToggle {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
  border: none;
}

#SearchLogo {
  color: white; 
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) To align the navigation, just add

```
#BrandDropdown {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

to your CSS. You can change the value until you have what you want. [**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/NTTpfDYu3f)

2.) You could use a CSS background image for the logo and exchange the image on `:hover`. Importing the image in a specific font is a bit too much imho. Here is a simple example on how to do it: [**Example CSS hover**](http://jsfiddle.net/rbvebgxj/). It should be self explaining.

Comment: 1.). Thanks, Ive tried that already before, but to no avail, none happened. :(
2.) Umm, can you please elaborate more on how to do that? I don't know what you mean by "exchange the image on :hover".

Comment: Did you look at the example I created with your code? It works there.. Or did I understand your question wrong?

Comment: 1.) Yes, I added that "margin-left: -15px", but the outcome didn't **align** with the edge of the navbar. :(

Comment: OOH, it worked, number 1! I think I just have imported the wrong file after all. Haha. Thanks anyway. :)